# Optimization of code for searching in db

Tags: c#, optimization, entity-framework

This is my code:

```
var test = (from x in myDb.myTable
            where (x.name == tmp || x.name == tmp2 || x.name == tmp3) && x.unit == u
            select x).FirstOrDefault();

if (test == null)
    test = (from x in myDb.myTable
            where (x.name == tmp || x.name == tmp2 || x.name == tmp3)
            select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

How to optimize it>?

Comment: Could you explain your logic? Why are you doing it this way? If there are rows with both `tmp` and `tmp2` (which are bad variable names, BTW) as their `name`, why is it okay to get any one of them? What is the schema of your table? How many rows does your table have? Does it have any indexes?

Comment: @svick tmp, tmp2 and tmp3 are basically the same string, but with different encoding.

Comment: @svick myTable has a primary key which is int and autoincremented. It doesn't have indexes.

Comment: Can't you modify your database so that it used only one encoding?

Comment: Also, are you performing this query in a loop, or something like that?

Comment: @svick Actually yes, this code is in a foreach loop.

Comment: @Srcee: Try to avoid the loop and change the condition to `tempNames.Contains(x.name)` where tempNames is a list containing the names. This will be translated to SQL `WHERE name IN ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")` and be much faster! Also don't compare to different encodings just because you are not sure which one is the right one. Figure out which one is the right one and use this one only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var test = (from x in myDb.myTable
            where (x.name == tmp || x.name == tmp2 || x.name == tmp3)
            select x)
           .AsEnumerable()
           .OrderBy(x => x.unit == u ? 0 : 1)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

I removed the `x.unit == u` condition. Instead I sort the items to make the ones where 
this condition would be met to appear first. `FirstOrDefault` then makes the rest.

I split the EF part from the LINQ-to-objects part with `AsEnumerable()` as I am not sure if EF can translate the order by to SQL. If it can, you can try this

```
var test = (from x in myDb.myTable
            where (x.name == tmp || x.name == tmp2 || x.name == tmp3)
            orderby x.unit == u ? 0 : 1
            select x)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer. But will you pls explain how will this fasten the execution?

Comment: @Srcee It will always make a single query, while your code might make two queries. Making smaller number of queries is usually more efficient.

Comment: @Srcee: You did not specify what you wanted to have optimized (execution speed, code size, code maintainablity, others?). My solution will be faster, because it queries the database only once in any case.

Comment: I wanted to fasten the time, so I guess your solution will work.